# Word8 - ByteString encoding translations in Conduit

Tags: haskell, utf-8, character-encoding, telnet, conduit

I'm trying to get a telnet client working as a side project, and I saw this [gist](https://gist.github.com/erikd/1596792) as a basic example. When I compile and run it in ghci, however, you see that the encodings get garbled. Here is a reference of the characters:

```
���� ��#��'
```

My guess is that this is due to Conduit defaulting to UTF-8 for all transmission, when telnet uses a [7-bit ASCII / special telnet bit for codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet#History_and_standards). Also, would stdout / the terminal be able to directly interpret UTF-8, without having to do any conversions?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

conduit doesn't make any assumptions about character encoding, the functions you're using from that gist all operate purely at the binary level. It seems like the telnet server you're connecting to is (unsurprisingly) sending out non-ASCII data as special commands, and you're sending them directly to the terminal, which does not have any way to display them.

Comment: I see, I was thinking about using some of the functions in Data.Text.Encoding, I was particularly interested in `decodeASCII` - I'm just hoping that it throws-away anything that uses the extra bit. I'm gonna do some more digging, but this is definitely on the right track. Thank you!

Comment: This is probably a silly question, and not really your designation, but do you know if the terminal negotiates which encoding it expects with the program or pipe? I'm just wondering what the default encoding is. My guess is UTF-8, or something that allows for strange characters.

Comment: I see Data.Conduit.Text has some work done, however I still don't think this is gonna be enough (sadly). I'm still tinkering, I'll advise you of any updates or pull requests to add for special encoding translation.

Do you think there could be a Conduit-like framework for transferring data between nodes, but in an encoding-sensative way? Maybe with "translations", and "available" encodings? Maybe this way, more of the data type matching can be done automatically. Call it "Plug" haha.